# ionic PWA --prod flag not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, progressive-web-apps

I have a strange problem,

When I build PWA in dev mode using this command: `npm run ionic:build`
It works and build.

But when I use prod build: `npm run ionic:build –prod`, it doesn't build it and stuck at copy finished at.

I have added link for image below. I have done lots of search on google and finds no solution.

[image: Click here to see screenshot]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projects with Ionic 3 & Firebase: There is a version incompatibility between ionic app scripts and fireabse dependencies. Try to downgrade firebase to 4.12.1

Comment: Yes, It really helps me. It worked like charm! Thank you.

Comment: Any help regarding this issue -->

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51120230/why-ionic-pwa-increasing-cache-storage

Answer (score 1):

app-scripts from ionic 3 seem to be broken. Try run manually there params all at once.

```
ionic cordova build --aot --minifycss --minifyjs --optimize-js
```

If does not work try to remove optimize-js or minifyjs.

Comment: It is working; I know but problem with --prod.  These params are working.  I am using them currently.

Comment: Could you paste your pacakge.json please?

Comment: Here is the google docs link for package.json:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_ptRxLkcExSN3Y-TDpGSi4kH_X5qJVMYnahKGIPL5gU/edit

Comment: OK: there is a version incompatibility between ionic and fireabse. Try to downgrade firebase to 4.12.1 and let me know.

Comment: Wowwww. It works man. Thanks alot. You are great. I was stucked from 10 days. Why I haven't posted issue here before. Thanks.

Comment: I have another question. I am unable to post here (Stack overflow said you reached maximum questions limit).

Please help, If you can solve it for me. I will be thankful to you.

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-pwa-increasing-cache-storage/133685

Comment: Wait a bit until Stackoverflow let you post that question here. I will try to answer. In the main time you can upvote me :)